# How to populate Title column with name column content

Tags: lookup-column

In a doc library, the Title column is blank but the Name column contains the filename of the document uploaded. I want to concatenate (?) the Title column to auto fill-in what the Name column contains. Is there a simple calculated formula to use? My point in doing this is to create a lookup column from a List to include the name(s) of the documents in a Doc Library, yet the only seemingly relevant columns I can "lookup" are the Title column, which is not blank in that Doc Lib list.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 4):

As per document library field Title column is Single line of text.
so you are not able to change the type of Title column to Calculated column.

So There is one option,  you can auto populate Name field value in Title.

you can use declarative workflow.

[image]

you can use Set Filed in current item action

Comment: I don't see how/where you do that.  I tried adding set title to [%current Item:Name%] editing the Title but it didn't populate Title.  Name doesn't have anything to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the suggested Workflow method to rename new added items

For existing items, 
Open a Document Library,
run this script from [a (Chrome) F12 Dev Tools Snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets),
or as a [Bookmarklet in any browser](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/)

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var listGuid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(listGuid);
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
var items = list.getItems(query);
ctx.load(items);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(processItems);

function processItems(sender, args) {
    var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var id = item.get_id();
        var title = item.get_item('Title');
        var fileName = item.get_item('FileLeafRef');
            console && console.log('Renaming Title to:', fileName);
            item.set_item('Title', fileName);
            item.update();
            ctx.executeQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

iJSOM

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd need to make the Title column optional, which would require creating a content type.  You could then create a SharePoint Designer workflow that would populate the Title with the contents of Name whenever the item is edited.